# Split ruby string to()and inside()

Tags: ruby, regex

i need  split sting in ruby

i have string

```
'some text (text)'
```

i want to split it to () and inside ()

like this 'some text' text

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try this of expression.which is `return` the `list`.

```
  (/[*(*)]/)
```

http://regexpal.com/

[image]

Comment: exactly what i'm looked for,tnx

Comment: please do not use images like that, use text and format it with as code.

Comment: The two asterisks are meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

```
  (.*?)\((.*?)\)
```

See demo.Catch the two groups.

http://regex101.com/r/uR2aE4/1